# Datapusher memory error datastore

Tags: ckan

**CKAN Version if known (or site URL)**:
Latest

**Please describe the expected behavior**:
Large files get uploaded to the `datastore` with the `datapusher`.

**Please describe the actual behavior**:
Everything works perfectly when uploading normal sized files.

However, when trying to upload **large csv files (750 mb, not SO large but still)** with the datapusher to the datastore, I get this error :

```
_"Job "push_to_datastore (trigger: RunTriggerNow, run = True, next run at: None)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 364, in push_to_datastore
    f = cStringIO.StringIO(response.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 359, in read
    return buf.getvalue()
MemoryError"_
```

I changed the memory allowed size in the datapusher_settings.py, on my ckan conf file, in my nginx_proxy_cache, but I don't see what's wrong.

More details of what I changed :

`ckan.max_resource_size = 5120` in production.ini

`MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 1024000000` in https://github.com/ckan/datapusher/blob/master/datapusher/jobs.py#L28

The cache size in proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:30m max_size=250m;
and the `client_max_body_size 10000M;` in nginx conf file.

I do need help for this. 
Thanks in advance, 
Twinko5